# How to put override func before viewDidLoad()?

Tags: swift

Open ViewController.swift for editing, and before viewDidLoad() put the code below the question into the default code of ViewController.Swift?
How do I put these 4 lines of code below using the directions above into the default code for ViewController.Swift?

```
override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
}
```

Default code ViewController.Swift:

```
import UIKit  

class ViewController: UIViewController {  
    override func viewDidLoad() {  
        super.viewDidLoad()  
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {  
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you have a storyboard in which `ViewController` is defined. If so, you must not override `loadView()`:

> If you use Interface Builder to create your views and initialize the view controller, you must not override this method.

(from `UIViewController` class reference)

Instead edit the class of the view in the storyboard and set it to `WKWebView`. To get the `webView` reference, create it as an outlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
```

And link it as a referencing outlet to the view in the storyboard.

(Or you could just put the `WKWebView` inside the default `UIView`; would be simpler. You could do this either programmatically in `viewDidLoad()` or via the storyboard.)

**Or if you don't have a storyboard**, then just copypaste the code into the editor inside the `class` but outside the existing functions?

Answer (score -1):

```
import UIKit  

class ViewController: UIViewController { 

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {  
        super.viewDidLoad()  
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {  
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()  
    }  
}
```

However, it matters not where the func goes in the class:

```
import UIKit  

class ViewController: UIViewController { 
    override func viewDidLoad() {  
        super.viewDidLoad()  
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {  
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()  
    }  

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
}
```